# Instrumentation amplifier first design

Tags: operational-amplifier, instrumentation

What are the steps to design an instrumentation amplifier using lm741 with gain=100 ?

Comment: Is this school work?

Comment: Even some of us with grey hair were not yet practicing engineering when the 741 op-amp was first produced.

Comment: [Reasons not to use a 741 op-amp](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/304521/reasons-not-to-use-a-741-op-amp/304522#304522) - even more so when trying to build in instrumentation amplifier.

Comment: A warm welcome to the site. Please note that it's not a free design house, homework-answering service or on-line technical encyclopaedia, copied out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your question shows you've already done as much as you possibly could - which yours doesn't, I'm afraid. Please edit your question and greatly improve it. Show your own work and own findings in considerable detail with any schematic. The schematic tool here is easy to use. The better the quality of your question, the better the quality of the answers it will attract. Again, welcome.

Answer (score 6):

0. Determine the requirements.
1. Determine the topology to use (eg. 2 or 3 amplifiers).
2. Determine the resistor values.
3. Analyze the circuit to see if it meets all the requirements simultaneously. Iterate if required.
4. (optional) Throw away LM741s and use more modern amplifiers or a purpose-built instrumentation amplifier.